Has mandated/suggested cycling liability insurance been implemented successfully in any jurisdiction?
Any time a few cyclists organize a group ride, more seasoned riders come over and whisper to the organizers that they are taking a risk. Bicycle riding (blissfully) does not require liability insurance, but things can go wrong. To see why such an insurance might at least sometimes be desirable, read this answer.
From this cautious (perhaps overly so) perspective there are three directions.

Abandon organizing group rides for other than friends and family.
Proceed with bike rides, with fingers crossed.
Negotiate with an insurer, require membership, and ask members to purchase insurance.

This last option is a major hassle. It basically means establishing yet another bicycle-riding club. There are many around, with major bureaucratic elements that easily turn off all but the most committed riders. Those who want to ride 5 to 20 km each week will just walk away. And yet a strong leisurely participation is the best advocate for arguing to city councils the necessity of building better cycling infrastructure.
I'm wondering if a fourth option has been implemented successfully in your jurisdiction.
It would work like this. (Please don't gasp.) Liability insurance would be either required or suggested by the municipality, or by the state/province. Perhaps it can be (heavily) subsidized as bike riders consume no gas, do not wear out the roads, and, more importantly, cannot (easily) cause serious accidents.
Has mandated/suggested cycling liability insurance been implemented successfully in any jurisdiction? Has any method been suggested for eliminating, or at least reducing, liability risks from cycling enthusiasts who organize group rides?

The title question is a poll. Stack Echange is not for polls. For not a poll ask for a list of coutries that mandate it or whether there is any such country or something else actually answerable.

@VladimirFГероямслава How's the new title? Can you answer this new question?

I have not heard of such a country (but I only care about individuals), only for e-bikes above 25 km/h or above 250 W. Organized group rides are not much a thing here, unfortunately. For normal riding a pay for a voluntary general liability insurance for generic issues between citizens.

Just a note on the question: the title is about personal 3rd party liability (=compensation for damage caused by you do when riding your bike), but the text of the question is more about organiser 3rd party liability (=compensation for damage caused by participants of an activity you organise). From an insurance point of view, these are separate matters, as you don't have control on the doings of other people.

I'm not sure whether I'm being naive for missing the point or whether this should be an answer but in Germany and afaik most of continental Europe people generally have (and are legally required to have) a generic liability insurance. That should cover the kind of situation described in your linked law question. Nothing specific related to cycling or groups of bycycles needed.

Your assumption (or at least the assumption of the whisperers) is that the people inviting to the group ride suddenly bear liability for member accidents and related third party damage. That is probably not so for informal groups in many jurisdictions, although IANAL. (The U.S. appear to have a broader liability law though than most.)

I asked a question over at law regarding group ride liability.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica the people inviting to the group ride suddenly bear liability for member accidents and related third party damage: from what I got when I was organising hikes on meetup.com, it is in fact the case (Belgium/France - the law doesn't make a distinction between public and private activities). In practice, there is (or may be) some common sense in how these rules are applied, but the more severe the accident, the more likely that a "culprit" will be looked for (and even if a participant engages their own policy, the insurer can decide otherwise and go against the organiser)

@quarague: While personal liability insurance is common in Europe, I don't think it is mandatory anyhwere (certainly not in Germany). On specific types of liability insurance are mandatory, such as for motor vehicles, or for freelancers in some professions.

@quarague and that lack of 3rd party liability mandate probably contributes to the origin at the presumed liability of the organiser in many countries: if a serious accident occurs, someone will have to pay. If the responsible of the deed doesn't have an insurance, there's a risk that it will cascade to the organiser, as a causal link exists between the activity and the accident. But for organisers, it's in practice impossible to get an insurance outside the common frameworks (that is club/federation), as insurance companies will claim that these frameworks exist for that purpose.

The following answer is valid for Belgium. Liability insurance is only required for organizing activities (and riding fast e-bikes, but I guess it's out of scope of your question). Family third-party liability insurances cover cycling with friends and family (but only damages to third parties), this insurance is not mandatory, but recommended.
The 4th option is not so much of a hassle in Belgium: insurances are managed at federation level (by taking a license, there's a leisure one (30€/y) and a competition one (108€/y)), not at club level. Clubs are usually not 100% in order from an administrative point of view, so this split is done to make sure that the actual coverage for the members/organizers does not depend on the administrative rigour of the club.
The federation insurance includes a complementary third party liability insurance, complementary health coverage and road assistance. You get a license through a club, or without being part of a club (and if you are member of several clubs, you only need one license, so club memberships fees are typically split between license and club. This structure is also used in many other sports.
So a club can be an association de fait (association where members are collectively liable, but for matter related to cycling itself, the federation takes over, so the risk is limited for the organizers). But such club will require that participants to activities have a license from a cycling federation, so that organizers are covered.
Now if you want to organize public group rides, without requiring a license from the participants, then indeed, you enter into a mess from insurance point of view. Federation licenses for events exist, but from what I understood, it's mostly designed to 'events', rather than 'group rides'. There are possibilities to include non-affiliated riders in club rides, but I'm not aware of the formalities for cycling (it's usually limited to initiation rides though).

Nice. I see that it even includes bike theft (https://www.assurances.be/assurance-velo-omnium-velo-en-belgique).

@Sam7919 No, these are personal bike insurance that you typically take if you take a bike leasing (or want the best coverage), not the federation one. That’s the leisure one: http://www.fcwb.be/page3.asp?PageGroupeID=344&SelectedSectionMenu=342&ParentSectionMenuAff=344&ClubID=563&LG=FR

In Switzerland there used to be a bicycle insurance yearly sticker system. IIRC (it was years ago), it cost about $5 from the post office.  No details were needed, if the sticker was on the bicycle, it was insured.

But I have just read that it was phased out in ~2012 for being too expensive (not sure?). I personally thought it was rather a good system.
In New South Wales Australia, the club "Bicycle NSW", implements insurance as part of membership.  This was good while it was "Member and Family", but then they changed to wanting full insured details like names/birthdates/etc. and I dropped it.  I wasn't prepared to give-over all that information on my kids, as it looked like a bit of an information-gathering expedition by the insurer.
But, as you say this requires a club.
EDIT: $10 -> $5 after comment

One of the reasons that the mandatory bicycle liability insurance was phased out in Switzerland is because it's common (but not mandatory) to have a private liability insurance, often covering an entire household. These now cover bicycles as well.
Source: https://www.astra.admin.ch/astra/de/home/dokumentation/medienmitteilungen/anzeige-meldungen.msg-id-41706.html (available in German, French and Italian, only).

Switzerland: the price was about 5 CHF and as you wrote you could get it at the post office. You got a paper with the sticker and it also contained a form where you entered your details (name/address) and those of the bicycle, including make, color and frame number. This you had to keep as proof of insurance. The sticker on the bicycle was so that police could check whether you had current insurance. If you didn't, you got a fine. I'm confident that "less work for police" was a significant factor in the decision of phasing this system out.

Did the system have any provision for owners of multiple bicycles, or did each need to be registered separately?

There are two good questions about bicycle registration, for the interested, one about Belgium that includes an answer about Switzerland, and one general one.
